# Open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology

Is every connected open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$?  I'm considering on $\Bbb R^n$ the topology induced by a norm (considering $\Bbb R^n$ as a vector space).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say 'connected'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for instance, the (open) ball radius 1 centered at the origin, unioned with the ball of radius 1 centered at $(10,10,10,\ldots,10)$ is not connected and so can't be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

With the edit, no unless $n=1$. For $n\neq 1$, you can take $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$. This is open, but it's $n-1$st homotopy group is not $0$, so it can't be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is contractible.

For $n=1$ any open connected subset is an open interval which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.